# Can't addClass() to an object after passing it through a function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that passes through an object in its parameter, and then does something with that object.

```
function theFunction (theButton) {
    theButton.addClass('inactive');
}

$('.button').click(function () {
    theFunction($(this));
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't apply that class to the button. What am I missing here?

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNYmd/) with the code in.

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/hNYmd/6/

Comment: ummm turn jQuery on for your fiddle maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/hNYmd/7/

Comment: load jquery in your fiddle

Comment: Problem in jsfiddle, not loaded jquery refernce but i am sure you are not doing this direct in jsfiddle, so are you really missing same reference in your code also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not loading any jQuery

I have updated your fiddle

**SEE**

http://jsfiddle.net/hNYmd/4/

update your code also

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function () {
            theFunction($(this));
            return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works well. You just forgot to include `jquery` to the fiddle. Here is the corrected one: http://jsfiddle.net/hNYmd/3/

Answer (score 1):

you should put your code on dom ready like this ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hNYmd/14/)

```
    function theFunction (theButton) {
        theButton.addClass('inactive');
    }
    $(function(){
        $('.button').click(function () {
            theFunction($(this));
            return false;
        })
    })
```